# How to get attached file from NetSuite record

Tags: file, netsuite

Have some troubles with automatic uploading files from NetSuite. For example:
I need uploaded files from SuiteScript (RESTlet), attached to one of employee (Communication -> File subtab).

For attaching files, we can use `nlapiAttachRecord()`, but I can't get file subrecord, looks like there is no file attachment record at all. 
Please, advice, how i can get attached file from NetSuite record in SuiteScript.

Comment: Just a clarification, you want to make the files attached to a record looks like a sublist?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to get list already attached files (attached to any record). In forms (Employee, Vendor, etc.) files look like sublist, but I can't get this sublist in script.

Comment: Solved with help user prasun - was created saved search, in saved search we can access file fields found "File Fields..." in the end of list enable fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pull attached files from a record, one way could be defining a saved search from UI and then accessing that search in your code. Steps to define the search is mentioned in the [Suite Answer](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26974/kw/get%20attached%20record)  (To access this link you must be logged into your NetSuite Account)

Comment: Thank you for great idea, i try it, and share my results.

Comment: Can you please more detailed tell how i can add files to saved search? I have not  any Entity like file or mediaitem, if i create search for emloyee, i cant access file fields, just can add it as criteria.

Comment: On Employee search you can pull file fields both in search results column as well as criteria. You can put a criteria in employee search "File:Name is not empty" and pull "File:Name" and "File:Internalid" in search results. To pull file fields in criteria you will see "File Fields..." in the select drop down of criteria/search results

Comment: Thank you a lot,now I found "File Fields..." and it great solve for this issue!